# How to find in Linux if mule is running

Tags: services

When I try to get the status of `Mule` service in linux by this:

```
service mule status
```

I get this:

```
Usage: /etc/init.d/mule {start|stop|restart}
```

Apparently, mule service doesn't support status. How can I see that Mule is running then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want it to run just go:

```
service mule start
```

Or stop, go:

```
service mule stop
```

Then it will tell it is already in that state, or it will do it.

I also know a few services, where i need to do this.

Otherwise you can check with `ps`:

```
ps aux | grep mule
```

Should work...

Comment: Could you explain the last part `ps aux | grep mule`. I'm not interested in starting/stopping/restarting.

Comment: ps is the process command which will list all running processes, to see what actually is running you need the -aux flags. Check them out in the man! :-) ($ man ps). Then i pipe it over to grep, where i can find different parts of text from standard output based on string pattern. Then i just grab lines with "mule" from the list from ps. And there you got it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to see if the process itself runs with the command `ps`, as mentioned above. The List of current processes might be very long, and thus can either be filtered for a given string like `mule` with the command `ps -efH|grep mule` or it can be piped into a viewer: `ps -efH|less` where you can read through the command output.
Btw., `-e` tells the system to show all processes, `-f` makes sure additional information are output, and `-H` prints the information in a tree, showing process dependencies.

As an alternative, you could also (install and) launch the process viewer `htop`, which will show you all current processes with information like how many CPU is used my them, live.

Comment: He can also just use top...

Comment: Yeah, but I figured that for beginners htop is much easier to understand.

Comment: Definitely, but worth learning top for flexiblity.

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing with [InSpec](https://www.inspec.io):

```
describe service("mule") do
  it { should be_installed }
  it { should be_enabled }
  it { should be_running }
end
```

Answer (score -1):

It should be great include which version of Mule you are running, in any version 3.x.x you can go to **%MULE_HOME%/bin** and run the command:

```
./mule status
```

and it will give you and output like this if is running:

```
MULE_HOME is set to /opt/MuleSoftESB/mule-Poc
Mule Enterprise Edition is not running.
```

or if is not running:

```
MULE_HOME is set to /opt/MuleSoftESB/mule-Poc
Mule Enterprise Edition is running (12403).
```

Other option is, into the same bin directory, list the files (`ls -la`) including the hidden files and if you see a file called:

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 wasadmin devwas     6 Apr  2 17:45 .mule_ee.pid
```

Then the Mule server is running for sure.